# How to choose the elements from the jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry for stupid title.

Problem: I need to select only .special element from $elements variable.

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element special"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
var $elements = $('.element'),
    $special  = $element.find('.special'); // Not working.
```

UPD:
Please, don't write something like "$('.element.special')". It's wrong for my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $elements = $('.element'),
    $special  = $element.filter('.special');
```

Since the element you are targeting is a member of the `$element` set, you need to use `.filter()`, [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is used to find descendant members of the elements in the calling set

Answer (score 3):

< div class="element">bbb< /div>
< div class="element special">aaa< /div>
< div class="element">aaa< /div>

```
var $special = $('.element.special');
$special.html("test");
```

Comment: Guys, it's ok, but I say ".element.special" it's wrong selector for my case, cuz i need to filter .special from other .element, but not select. Why you didn't read before answer?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
var $special = $('.element.special');
```

Comment: OP: "UPD: Please, don't write something like "$('.element.special')". It's wrong for my case."